# How do I return a pointer to a node nested as the value of a map? (Access violation)

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes, access-violation

So I'm trying to create my own graph interpretation with a linked list;

Essentially, I want to create nodes linked to other nodes by n/e/s/w coordinates and every time I create a node, these nodes get added to a list I can check on later called 'Exists'(if it exists).

I reflect on the pair 'yx' coordinates of these nodes to confirm that. This is what my header looks like this:

```
class Graph {
private:
    struct Area {
        pair<int , int> yx;
        Area *north;
        Area *east;
        Area *south;
        Area *west;
    };

    Area *Start;
    Area *Current;
    map<pair<int, int>, Area*> Exists; //Need to get the stored Area from this map
public:

    Graph();
    void Create();

    //Add_Node calls Connect_Nodes()
    void Add_Node(Area before, int code, int symbol, int color, pair<int,int> yx, string title, string description, int coordinate);
    //Connects nodes if the key is found in the map
    Area* Connect_Nodes(pair<int, int> yx, int coordinate);
};
```

Here is the implementation, Add_Node() called first in void Create():

```
Add_Node(*Start, 00001, '.', 3, Start->yx, "Hallway", "Halls", 1);
```

Add_Node Calls the connection next:

```
void Graph::Add_Node(Area before, pair<int, int> yx, ... int coordinate){
    Area *ptr = Connect_Nodes(yx, coordinate);
```

And the Connect method:

```
Graph::Area* Graph::Connect_Nodes(pair<int,int> yx, int coordinate) {
    pair<int, int> temp;
    switch (coordinate) {
    case 1:
        temp.first = ++yx.first;
        temp.second = yx.second;
        break;
      ....
    }
    map<pair<int, int>, Area*>::iterator it;
    it = Exists.find(temp);
    if (it != Exists.end())
        return it->second;
    else return nullptr;
}
```

I'm probably missing something important with my pointer implementations, I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.
std::_String_alloc<std::_String_base_types<char,std::allocator<char> > >::_Get_data(...) returned 0x14.
```

I can create the nodes just fine, however, in a Display() method, ptr iterates to the node, when I run ptr->title on the created node, I get the read access violation. What could be causing this error?

I hope I've documented this  well enough to be understood.

---

Edit: Step through discovered the following in my un-posted Add_Node method:

```
void Graph::Add_Node(Area before,  pair<int, int> yx,  int coordinate){
    bool passed = true;
    Area *ptr = Connect_Nodes(yx, coordinate);
    if (ptr != NULL) {
        switch (coordinate) {
        case 1:
            before.north = ptr;
        case 2:
            before.east = ptr;
        case 3:
            before.south = ptr;
        case 4:
            before.west = ptr;
        }
    }
    else {
        do
        {
            Current = new Area;
            Current_Code++;
            Current->code = Current_Code;
            switch (coordinate) {
            case 1:
                if (before.north == NULL)
                {
                    Current->yx.first = ++before.yx.first;
                    Current->yx.second = before.yx.second;
                    Exists[Current->yx] = Current;
                    before.north = Current;  // PROBLEM LINE
                    return;
                }
```

When I replaced before.north in the above code with Start->north I was able to display everything just fine without any errors!

```
Start->north = Current;
```

However, since I used the before instance throughout the code it will need an adjustment to work.

The idea is that 'before' signifies an existing node that would connect to the node to be added.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: The debugger didn't throw any errors, and everything works fine if I do not call the Display() method. I'm reading about the causes of access violation, and I suppose it might point to the fact that the node I created in Create() no longer exists in Display()? That could be the cause of the violation. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: You probably misunderstood what I meant with the _debugger_, that's not your compiler.

Comment: IMHO, a graph representation in C++ would not require anything more complicated than a vector<vector<T>> (where, T is the type of your nodes). This is the adjacency list representation - every nodes points to list of nodes that it connects to. (You can choose to have a matrix representation if need be). You don't seem to have shared the full driver, where these things are being used from. As other commentators have pointed out, it would be easier to look into this if you step through the code and show us where things go wrong.

Comment: The restriction is my own, I've made a matrix counterpart and just wanted to see how far I could get this idea while I practice pointer usage. Like both of you have said, I've stepped through the code and found the culprit in the yet un-posted Add_Node method (Added to the edit) apparently using 'before' caused issues. (Full description above) What seems to be the problem with it? I'm guessing it is because i'm not passing a pointer of Area, and instead, an instance of it?

Comment: @Arvayne *while I practice pointer usage* -- What is there really to practice?  You know pointers must point to somewhere valid, and that they need to be dereferenced to access the value being pointed to.  What you're doing is taking this basic concept and trying to make something complex out of it, thus creating code that is hard to maintain, debug, and even fix (if you do find the error).

Comment: @Arvayne If the goal is to create a graph class, using standard components (map, vector, std::list, etc), should be the way to accomplish this.  It isn't as if the graph class automatically writes itself if you used those components -- you still have to write the code to glue everything together, and that still takes some thinking.   Overusing pointers just takes the focus off your real goal, and instead you're fighting with pointer issues.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, I understand your point completely, however, perhaps pointers was the wrong word for it, of course what I'm really practicing is C++, (from the bottom up to modern concepts) doing these exercises gets me familiar with the type of environment and appreciate the newer stuff. I come from a background of C# so I'm already aware of most of the simplified implementations. Overall I'm still a beginner, I'm not really in a position to be able to tell usefulness(down the line) apart. I simply practice what is encountered.

Comment: The "bottom up" is now moving away from using raw pointers and instead use the standard components, smart pointers, etc.  You could have started by attempting to write a string class or vector class, which use pointers, and basically you will learn 99% of what you need to know about pointers (in addition to copy construction, assignment operator, etc).  Second, code where you are using standard components in one place, and then totally abandon usage of them in another place in the same program, just doesn't look "correct", or at least, the program is put together in a strange fashion.

Comment: In the future when you get a specific error you want to ask a question about, the first things you should do is copy/paste the entire error including line number and file name, and then include the exact line of code (and some surrounding code for context) into your question. You initially posted a bunch of code unrelated to the error, posted the error that was clearly about `string` usage, and didn't post any code using `string`s. Then when you finally posted the function in question, you changed the arguments so it no longer takes a string as a parameter.

Comment: You pass `before` to `Add_Node` by value. Any modifications the function applies to `before` are not reflected in the calling code. `*Start` remains as it was before `Add_Node` call.